# Access MSI properties from within an installer helper class

Tags: .net-4.0, wix, windows-installer

I have a which extends System.Configuration.Install.Installer, which is run during install time of our application. I need to access some properties that are set in the MSI file (e.g. INSTALLDIR, and some other paths I need to retrieve). Is there a way to access MSI properties from within a helper assembly?

It may be worthy to note that our installer is built using WiX 3.5.

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

**EDIT** Here is our current code in the class.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
   public class MxServeInstaller : Installer
   {
      private ServiceInstaller myServiceInstaller;
      private ServiceProcessInstaller myServiceProcessInstaller;

      public MyProductInstaller()
      {
         this.myServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
         this.myServiceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
         this.myServiceInstaller.ServiceName = MyProduct.SERVICE_NAME;
         this.myServiceInstaller.Description = "Provides software copy protection and token pool management services for the Mx-Suite from Company";
         this.myServiceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string[] { "Crypkey License" };

         Installers.Add(this.myServiceInstaller);

         this.myServiceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
         this.myServiceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;         
         Installers.Add(this.myServiceProcessInstaller);
      }

      public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
      {
         base.Install(stateSaver);
         ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(MyProduct.SERVICE_NAME);
         try
         {
            controller.Start();
         }
         catch( Exception ex )
         {
            string source = "My-Product Installer";
            string log = "Application";
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
               EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);

            EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
            eventLog.Source = source;
            eventLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Failed to start My-Product!{1}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
         }
      }
   }
```

What I plan on adding is a phase for AfterInstall, which at the very least needs to know the INSTALLDIR property set in the installer.

Comment: How does the installer class "run during install time"? Is it a custom action? Some code sample could be useful...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works, this is my first time working with System.Configuration.Install.Installer, and I am working with code that has already been created and known to work. It looks like this code is automatically run when we install the service as a part of the installer, so this code should execute, I just need to know how to access properties that were set in the MSI (which I imagine isn't a farfetched request for an installer helper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installer class custom actions run out of process and it's impossible to directly access the MSI handle and any associated functions such Get/Set Properties and logging.

The solution is to use Windows Installer XML Deployment Tools Foundation custom actions ( google WiX DTF )  instead.  This is a much better pattern for managed code custom actions and will simply change the hosting model and provide you a Session class to be able to talk to MSI.   The rest of your code should then fit the box.

However, more to point.... I don't see anything in your custom action that actually requires a custom action.   Your real problem is that Visual Studio Deployment projects hide MSI's built in ability to create and start windows services.

See these blog articles for ideas on how to create a WiX merge module that uses the EventSource extension and ServiceInstall / ServiceControl elements to do all this work without any custom actions at all.  This creates a merge module that can then be added to your Visual Studio Deployment project.

[Redemption of Visual Studio Deployment Projects](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/03/redemption-of-visual-studio-deployment.html)

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

and finally why it's important that you do this:

[Zataoca: Custom actions are (generally) an admission of failure.](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/Zataoca-Custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure)

Comment: right now, there is no reason to run a custom action. i haven't looked at this class before yesterday, but everything we do can be done within the context of WiX. However, I am adding new functionality which will require the use of a custom action

Comment: Sorry if I misread the question. It looked like you were using a CA to install the service and eventsource and that's typically done by someone using VDPROJ.  People doing InstallShield and WiX don't typically use Installer class CA's.

Comment: As an aside, when you do write your first DTF custom action, be sure to use the immeadiate/deferred patterns (CustomActionData) and follow all best practices to get proper UAC and rollback behavior.